# How to use a free bootstrap template in meteor

Tags: meteor

How to use a free bootstrap template (e.g., from startbootstrap.com) in meteor. I mean where the resources- html file, css folders and js folders of the free template should be put and what packages are needed to add/remove in meteor project file? I have tried it several times but got errors and the program crashes each time. I also transfer the script and link tags from  section to  section, but it did not work.

Comment: Can you add more detail around what you've tried, what error message you're getting, and perhaps post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the css of the template to the client of your Meteor project. Also, try using the `nemo64:bootstrap` package for Bootstrap. This will add some files to your project automatically, one of which will say is editable at the top. You can put your custom css in that file.

You can put the relevant html, css, and js files anywhere on the client. (Sticking it inside a folder called `client` will do that).

Image and font files should go in a folder called `public`.

Comment: Yes, it helps me a lot. So much thanks to you. I was the problem with links and scripts. I move them from head to the body and then it works fine.

Comment: You shouldn't have to add links and scripts. Remove them for the app and things should still work fine

Comment: Thanks a lot. Removing links and scripts are also worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to make meteor *templates* from the HTML files. As is they will be missing any `<template name="foo">` tags.
2. The css files can go anywhere under /client and they will automatically be added to the project. These are the easy ones.
3. The js files are the harder ones. If you put these under /client they will be wrapped by Meteor and will not have global scope. In all probability they won't work at all. You can put them under /public and modify your head.html file to include them to get around that problem. Odds are there won't be very many js functions in the free template anyway so you might want to read through them and see which ones you really need and then convert those to be proper template helpers or global functions on the client.